# Can I get the benefits of both, objects and arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, object

I have parts of data tagged with IDs distributed in different collections.

I need to access this data directly with the ID, but I also need to loop over the data really fast.

```
var listOfPartA = { 
  34523: { foo: 7, bar: 123},
  6435: { foo: 2, bar: 163},
  3123: { foo: 3, bar: 223},
  ... 
};

var listOfPartB = { 
  34523: { baz: 1},
  6435: { baz: 4},
  3123: { baz: 6},
  ... 
};
```

If I need to get specific dataparts for an Id it's fast, but If I try to loop all the dataparts it's slow.

```
var listOfPartA = [ 
  { id: 34523, foo: 7, bar: 123},
  { id: 6435, foo: 2, bar: 163},
  { id: 3123, foo: 3, bar: 223},
  ... 
];

var listOfPartB = [ 
  { id: 34523, baz: 1},
  { id: 6435, baz: 4},
  { id: 3123, baz: 6},
  ... 
];
```

If I want to get specific dataparts for an ID of these objects it is slow, because I have to search for them manually, but If I loop over all dataparts it's fast.

Can't I have fast direct access and fast iteration?

Comment: You could always just use both. Arrays are assigned by reference, so there would be very little overhead memory-wise.

Comment: Use both on the same data. Keyword: index structures ;)

Comment: What if I want to delete the data to all IDs? I could do it fast in the object but wouldn't the array end up with dead references?

Comment: I mean delete all dataparts for one ID...

Answer (score 2):

Pre-index your array:

```
var listOfPartA = [
    {id:34523, foo:7 bar:123},
    ...
];

var lookupPartA = {};
listOfPartA.forEach(function(x,i) {lookupPartA[x.id] = i;});
```

Now, you can loop quickly with the `listOfPartA` array, but also find quickly:

```
listOfPartA[lookupPartA[34523]]
```

Comment: Doesn't it have to be `[x.id]` - besides well done hashindex :)

Answer (score 1):

Pre-index your object:

```
var lookupPartA = { 
  34523: { foo: 7, bar: 123},
  ... 
};

var listOfIds = Object.keys(lookupPartA);
```

Now, you can find ids quickly in the `lookupPartA` object, but also loop quickly:

```
for (var i=0, l=listOfIds.length; i<l; i++)
    lookupPartA[listOfIds[i]]
```

Comment: Here is a test, in which object.keys didn't have much benefit: http://jsperf.com/performance-of-array-vs-object/17

Comment: @K..: Notice that you don't have to execute `Object.keys` every time you loop the array, only when you insert/remove keys. Still, surprisingly it's faster than a `for in`-loop :-)

Comment: Ah, so you mean, the performance loss in the test comes from `Object.keys`?

Answer (score -1):

According to theses tests, **arrays are always fasters** than objects.

- [array vs object performance test](http://jsperf.com/array-vs-object-performance)
- [object vs array vs native linked list](http://jsperf.com/object-vs-array-vs-native-linked-list/14)
- [benchmark comparison](http://news.qooxdoo.org/javascript-array-performance-oddities-characteristics)